# Adding Peltier module to an evaporative cooler

Tags: fan, peltier, cooling

I'm planning to add a two Peltier module (TEC 12706 with heatsink on both sides) on a evaporative cooler but I cannot decide where should I put them.

Here's the idea:

[image]

Idea B would be good but I'm planning to use this fan in an small room. Humidity will rise and affect the evaporation process or ditch it and move the cooling element close to the air inlet of the centrifugal fan.

Comment: What is this supposed to cool? The room? Where do you put the waste heat of the peltier? into the room too? net effect: heating.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're actually trying to achieve here - or rather, how you're thinking this will improve the effectiveness of the setup.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_g4nT4a28U

He uses a desiccant solution through an evap cooler, prior to the main evap cooler to account for the humidity problem.